# ios tab bar click to show modal view get a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I want implement this animation effect(using storyboard), when user click a tab bar(say 2nd tab bar item), it displays the corresponding view like a modal view(display upwards to the screen)

My current method is delegate tab bar controller to tab bar and rewrite

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
    NSLog(@"rawr");
    NSLog(@"inside tab bar did select, index is %d", self.selectedIndex);

    if (item == [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]) {
        //item.title = @"modal view";
        NSLog(@"going to promote as modal view");
        CBTab2ViewController* modalViewController = [[CBTab2ViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem is, the view displayed is a black screen, any idea how to implement it correctly?

my source code can be found a link below: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rd6ek59xf0yiq4/testtabbar.zip

Comment: It's because your CBTab2ViewController's background black. If you set the CBTab2ViewController's background color orange, you will see the orange colored screen =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines :

```
CBTab2ViewController* modalViewController = [[CBTab2ViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To this one (incase your storyboard name is "MainStoryBoard"):

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

CBTab2ViewController * modalViewController = (MyViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CBTab2ViewController"];

[self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: great, rocks, it displays correctly. currently in storyboard there is this connection between tab bar controller and tab bar item, it sill displays before the modal view, do you know how to hide the default tab bar view? to make the transition more natural, such as tumblr new post funciton

Comment: @air_bob Do u need more help?

Comment: for instance, tab2 view has this hello label, will show 2 times, the first time is the default tab bar behavior, 2nd time is modal view, I want make it display as a natural modal view(probably with a back button to dismiss it), user click back button to go back to previous tab bar view

Comment: @air_bob So add UINavigationController that will wrap your UIViewController (CBTab2ViewController).
Basically, U nee to create a UITabBarController that each tab is a UINavigationController, This way U have for each tab his own UIViewController stack.